# Unable to create instance from the Google Cloud SDK in a project or browse instances

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk

I am unable to connect to a project on Google Cloud using the cloud SDK. I want to upload file on my instance using SDK. The error I am getting is:

```
You are now logged in as [ishanatech@gmail.com].
Your current project is [Trial-2015-1].  You can change this setting by running:
  $ gcloud config set project PROJECT

C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute instances list

NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Invalid value 'Trial-2015-1'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z](
?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'


    C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute instances create instance-2 --image centos-6 --zone uscentral1-a

NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Failed to find image for alias [centos-6] in public image project [centos-cloud
]. Try specifying a different image using [--image].
 - Invalid value 'Trial-2015-1'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z](
?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'


    C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud compute instances create instance-2 --image opensuse-13 --zone uscentral1-a

NAME ZONE MACHINE_TYPE INTERNAL_IP EXTERNAL_IP STATUS
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Failed to find image for alias [opensuse-13] in public image project [opensuse-
cloud]. Try specifying a different image using [--image].
 - Invalid value 'Trial-2015-1'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z](
?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'
```

Answer (score 12):

If you look carefully at the complex RE the error message displays:

```
'(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\.)*(?:[a-z](
```

?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:a-z?))'

you'll spot that all the letters there are **lowercase** -- always carefully expressed as `a-z`.

`Trial-2015-1` starts with an **uppercase** letter, thus it's not deemed a valid project name.

Are you sure that your project isn't actually named `trial-2015-1`, with a leading **lowercase** initial...?

Answer (score 0):

i am getting the below error while creating Bastion sever using terraform script

Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource.name': 'Bastion-server'. Must be a match of regex '(?:a-z?)', invalid

Comment: B -> b (regex is telling you its all lowercase). You should not post questions in the asnwers section of someone elses question. Create a new question.